# How do I make it so that pdf outputs open in a maximized screen?

Tags: pdftex, pdf, viewers, adobe

I'm using a recent version of MikTeX and my pdf outputs open in a window not maximized. This is quite annoying.

> How can I make it so that they open in Adobe reader in a maximized window?

Please note that I **don't** want it to open in a fullscreen presentation mode, but just in a plain old maximized window. I've tinkered with the hyperref options 'pdfview' and 'pdfstartview', but nothing seems to work.

Moreover, I could not find a solution in these links:

http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf

http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb23-3-4/tb75feu.pdf

Comment: This is not a property that can be configured in the PDF file. This is an issue of the windows manager of the operating system. See [How to start Adobe Reader with window maximized?](http://superuser.com/q/640174).

Comment: I have no doubts that Heiko's answer is correct in the comment above. But since when do we close a question only because the answer today ends in that something is not possible?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Maybe it would be helpful to explain what is special about this functionality? That is, the question seems *prima facie* reasonable given that it is possible to set the PDF to open in presentation mode or in an ordinary window and that this can be configured in pdfLaTeX. Is this just not something covered by the PDF spec?

Comment: @cfr: Presentation mode is different, it is supported by the PDF specification and the PDF viewer might switch to full-screen with hidden GUI. But the size of the PDF viewer window, its position, ..., is nothing that should be set in a PDF file. It belongs to the window manager/operating system or the user interface of the PDF viewer. In my comment above I linked to a question, which has an answer that can be tried to configure Windows to open `.pdf` files with maximized viewer window. If a shortcut is used to open Acrobat Reader, then it can be configured in the properties of the shortcut.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks. I figured it was something like that. I just thought it might be helpful to have a comment here explaining *why* it was off topic since, from a user perspective, it is not obvious. (It is more so if you use GNU/Linux, I think, as you are more likely to be aware that windows *are* managed and that there is such a thing as a window manager. I suspect this is much less obvious to users of Windows and OS X unless they use X11 in OS X.)

Comment: @cfr: I would have voted for closing as duplicate. The system, however, does not allow duplicates that point to other sites. The reason for off-topic is already given in the first comment which includes a link to an answer (also pointing to a *non-TeX* site). It seems that you want to write an elaborate answer, thus I will vote for reopen. IMHO writing answers should be encouraged even for closed questions.

Comment: Heiko, thanks for your input. However, I already have done what was suggested in the link
http://blogmines.com/blog/2010/03/08/how-to-automatically-open-a-application-in-a-maximized-window/

and this did not work.

Comment: Also, don't pdf files just remember the way in which they were saved? If a save a pdf file in a maximized window, then it will reopen like that. So, Latex is automatically 'saving' them in a certain way when it creates them. I don't understand why this isn't a Latex problem.

Comment: May you please help me troubleshoot? Also, is there a solution different from the one in your link, one involving a little less back-door computer maneuvering (which is completely foreign to me)?

Comment: @JSeaton While I do know PDFs can contain some metadata for the window manager, I think [this particular behavior](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171334/#comment395306_171334) is something that Reader remembers by itself (unless the PDF file is confirmed to change, e.g. `shasum`/`diff`).